# How to segment Instagram ads data from Facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, instagram, ads

Im working on a project building a dashboard displaying data on a lot of metrics around Facebook page insights and advertising. For instance we are retrieving the metrics  post_impressions_by_paid_non_paid and post_impressions_by_paid_non_paid_unique (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/insights).

Does anyone know if it is possible to segment numbers for paid impressions on Facebook from paid impressions on Instagram? Is there another part of the api that enable that kind of segmentation for corresponding data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is only possible in the marketing api. To segment by instagram you have to be able to pull the data and request or filter by placement. Anything on instagram has the placement instagramstream.

Comment: @SheriefBadran I'm stuck with a similar problem. Which API endpoint did you use to solve it?